# Converting Dynamic HTML TO PDF using html2pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, html2pdf

The pages I want to convert are generated dynamically via PHP from a MySQL database. In other words the information on a page depends on the Id of the chosen object. So I would normally have a URL like this

```
renal_prescRequest_review.php?id=4
```

I am using `html2pdf` and so far I am unable to perform the conversion. When I pass `id=2` directly like this

```
// get the HTML
ob_start();
include("renal_clinicalTrial_review.php?id=2");
$content = ob_get_clean();`
```

I get these errors:

> Warning: include(renal_prescRequest_review.php?id=2) [function.include
>   ]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in/home/renalmed/public_html/testing/test/renal_prescRequest_pdf.php
>   on line5
>
> Warning: include(renal_prescRequest_review.php?id=2)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in /home/renalmed/public_html/testing/test/renal_prescRequest_pdf.php
>   on line5
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'renal_prescRequest_review.php?id=2' for
>   inclusion(include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in/home/renalme/public_html/testing/test/renal_prescRequest_pdf.php on
>   line5.

The fascinating thing is that these errors are thrown on the PDF document where the actual HTML is supposed to be displayed. I have been on this for quite a while now. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include a query string on the include file.

One solution on this is to transfer the codes of renal_prescRequest_review.php in the file where you want to convert html to pdf.

Below is the sample code.

```
<?php
/**
 * HTML2PDF Librairy - example
 *
 * HTML => PDF convertor
 * distributed under the LGPL License
 *
 * @author      Laurent MINGUET <webmaster@html2pdf.fr>
 *
 * isset($_GET['vuehtml']) is not mandatory
 * it allow to display the result in the HTML format
 */
// get the HTML
ob_start();
// database connection here
require_once ( 'database-connection.php' );
// get the id
$id = $_GET['id'];
// Retrieve record from database
// query code here
?>
<page backleft="0mm" backtop="0mm" backright="0mm" backbottom="0mm">    
    ID: <?php echo $id;?>
    <!--other html and php codes here.-->
</page>
<?php
$content = ob_get_clean();
// convert to PDF
require_once('../html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
try
{
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', array(200,300), 'en', true, 'UTF-8', array(0, 0, 0, 0));
    //$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr', true, 'UTF-8', 0);
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
    //$html2pdf->Output('test.pdf','D'); // force download pdf
    $html2pdf->Output('test.pdf'); // display only
}
catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: If i understand you, you want me to place the code that converts to PDF in the same file as my HTML code. If this is what you're suggesting please shed some light as to how to go about this. If possible some codes. Thanks

Comment: In the code above, the page tags are meant to hold HTML but the HTML generated by this page is not static HTML. The page tags will have to be populated by database data. So they need to be within <?php ?> and they will have to be echoed to the page..

Comment: Yes you can replace the html code or php code inside the <page> tag. Do whatever you want to display inside the <page> tag. I updated the codes above. Please check and let me know if it answers your problem. If yes then kindly mark this as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this method works greatly. The only caveat is that the force download is obtrusive. Can you suggest a way to handle this perhaps with an event handler a link probably

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the download box from popping up by default. I want it to happen after an event occurs. It pops up even before my page is rendered and when it pops up the page does not display..

Comment: updated the code, please check above and mark this as an answer and mark this answer as useful. thanks.

Comment: How can i upload pdf file to amazon s3 bucket ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can use get variables in include. Use an url with file_get_contents function. Or remove the get variable id and assign it before the include, detect it with an isset within the included script.

Comment: could you please shed more light on this method, possibly with an example. I have never used html2pdf before and the examples don't say much about what I need.

Comment: Its not the pdf library that is having the issue but the php code. Remove id=2 from the file name within include.

Comment: How can i upload pdf file to amazon s3 bucket ?

Comment: @ShashankShah this is a separate question. Please start a new question. Or better still google this question as it has been asked lots before.

Comment: @user1367101 Brother, better answer the question which is asked to you i have already post a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293465/html2pdf-upload-pdf-file-dierctly-to-the-amazon-s3-bucket if you know it asked a lot before than post answer link rather than waste of comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: include(renal_prescRequest_review.php?id=2)
```

You can't include files like that. You're specifying a query string within the [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement, where PHP is simply expecting a path. So PHP is expecting to find a file called `renal_prescRequest_review.php?id=2` (in other words, it's not looking for `renal_prescRequest_review.php`). Your PHP should look like

```
include('renal_prescRequest_review.php');
```

Comment: That will not give OP the desired result though.

Comment: when I did that, the pdf page does not display. But this error message in French  :                                           ERREUR nÂ°3
Fichier : /home/renalmed/public_html/testing/test/html2pdf/_class/parsingHtml.class.php
Ligne : 117

Code HTML non valide, une balise est fermÃ©e en trop : <div>

HTML : ...lank">Save as PDF</a> </form>...

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like it's trying to read the URL. Without seeing the code itself I couldn't say why it's doing that tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session on this and remove the query string on the include file

```
session_start();
// get the HTML
ob_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = 2;
include("renal_clinicalTrial_review.php");
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

In the renal_clinicalTrial_review.php, put session_start();
and you can use now the session.

Comment: It does not work, I get an error in French:: ERREUR nÂ°3
Fichier : /home/renalmed/public_html/testing/test/html2pdf/_class/parsingHtml.class.php
Ligne : 117

Code HTML non valide, une balise est fermÃ©e en trop : <div>

HTML : ...lank">Save as PDF</a> </form>...

Comment: check renal_clinicalTrial_review.php file, maybe there is an error on your codes. The code provided should work because I already have tested it and applied it on some of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can not include the file like this :

```
include("renal_clinicalTrial_review.php?id=2");
```

You should do it like this :

```
include("renal_clinicalTrial_review.php");
```

The parameter is then passed to the calling page.

For example, if your code is saved as `test.php`, then call it like this:

```
test.php?id=2
```